# Cómo hago para que un botón no pierda su :focus al hacer click en cualquier parte de la página

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo un botón

```
<button class='btn-activa'>MOSTRAR DIV</button>
```

Que activa este div oculto

```
<div class='div-oculto' style='display: none; background: red; width: 400px; height: 400px;'>MOSTRANDO DIV</div>
```

En el css se activa con focus y llamando la clase

```
<style>
/* al dar click al boton activa el div */
.btn-activar:focus + .div-oculto {
display: block !important;
}
</style>
```

Lo que quiero lograr es que el :focus siga seleccionado al dar click en cualquier parte de la página ya que normalmente se pierde cuando se da click en cualquier lado y pues desaparece el div con la información, cosa que no quiero.

**Cómo puedo hacerlo?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sé hasta que punto hacerlo con focus es imprescindible, si quieres una solucion solo CSS, sin JS, otra cosa que puedes hacer es poner un checkbox oculto antes de `.div-oculto`, pones un label apuntando a ese checkbox en vez del boton y haces `#id_checkbox::checked + .div-oculto {`

Edito para poner un ejemplo

```css
.btn-activar {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #bbb;
  padding: .5em;
}

.div-oculto {
  display: none;
  background: red;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

#check {
  display: none;
}

#check:checked+.div-oculto {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label for="check" class='btn-activar'>MOSTRAR DIV</label> Que activa este div oculto

<input type="checkbox" id="check">
<div class='div-oculto'>MOSTRANDO DIV</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Prueba darle focus, aunque se le haga click al documento entero:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(){
   document.getElementsByClassName("btn-activa")[0].focus();
});
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Pues es esto o revisar si el div con la info está visible y detener la propagación del evento (para evitar que cambie el foco)